# Hibernate group results by name then get the most current date

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm using the following query to retrieve the following results.

```
List<TranslationStyleSheet> results = this.session.createCriteria(TranslationStyleSheet.class).list();

File_Name     Create_Date TimeStamp

PDF Version | 10/1/2012
PDF Version | 10/2/2012
PDF Version | 10/10/2012
TXT Version | 9/2/2012
DOC Version | 9/31/2012
DOC Version | 10/5/2012
```

From there I need to only return the most current file name excluding older results.

example

```
File_Name     Create_Date TimeStamp

PDF Version | 10/10/2012
TXT Version | 9/2/2012
DOC Version | 10/5/2012
```

I tried the following code without success.

```
List<TranslationStyleSheet> results = this.session.createCriteria(TranslationStyleSheet.class)
            .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("fileName"))
            .add(Projections.max("createDate")))
            .list();
```

Does anybody know how to accomplish this? I first get an exception that says [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to org.mycompany.test.entities.TranslationStyleSheet

When I iterate the results, I only get one in return.

**UPDATE**

I was able to get the filtering to work properly with the following query, however I'm not sure how I could return a TranslationStyleSheet obj rather than just pieces of it.

query

```
List results = this.session.createCriteria(TranslationStyleSheet.class)
            .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("fileName"))
            .add(Projections.max("createDate")))
            .list();

    List<Object[]> objs = results;

    for (Object[] obj : objs ) {
        System.out.println(obj[0] + " " + obj[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wont doing an orderBy fix your problem?

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-ordering

```
addOrder(Order.desc("date"))
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that would resolve my issue. I can only get it to return one result if I iterate the list. I can't seem to cast the result to my TranslationStyleSheet object.